# How to enable textselection in pdfrenderer c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, pdf-viewer, pdfium

I am not able to select text in the pdfviewer which uses pdfRenderer(pdfiumViewer). Is there anyway to enable textSelection.

```
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => this.Controls.Clear()));
            pdfViewer = new PdfRenderer();

            pdfViewer.Visible = true;
            pdfViewer.Enabled=true;

            pdfViewer.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;


            var pdfDocument = PdfDocument.Load(fileStream);
            pdfViewer.Load(pdfDocument);
            pdfViewer.ZoomMode = PdfViewerZoomMode.FitBest;

            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => pdfViewer.Focus()));

            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => this.Controls.Add(pdfViewer)));
```

Here, i dont get any option from PdfRenderer to enable textselection.
Any help would be very kind.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code you tried with.

Comment: i have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

You can't select text on a pdfRenderer, it's only for displaying the pdf content as pictures.
Rendering doesn't mean OCRizing, nor associating the pics with the text if the pdf is "questionnable".
Try another library like Pdfium.Net or iText7, but they're not free.